# Gremlin Python N-hop query

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlinpython

How can I get the list of nodes `N`-hops away from a given node (where `N` is a parameter)? Here, `N`-hops means we need to traverse (minimum) `N` edges (outward) from the source node to reach the destination node.

For `1`-hop, the query can be

```
g.V().hasLabel(source_node).outE().otherV().to_list()
```

What is an optimal query to generalise this to `N`-hop?

Comment: Do you want exactly N hops, or at least N hops but could be more?

Comment: At least `N` hops but could be more.